# How to add a 3rd party Log framework ( log4net ) to mvvmcross?

Tags: mvvmcross

I would like to use log4net in mvvmcross to replace MvxDebugTrace, but I don't want to change the core source code, is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugtrace is initialised inside setup in `InitializeDebugServices`.

Currently this is implemented on each platform using these steps (example is from Android):

- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Platform/MvxAndroidSetup.cs#L65
- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxSetup.cs#L55

This `InitialiseDebugServices` method is marked as virtual - so you can override it in your own Setup.cs class within each platform.

For building a bridge from mvx to log4net, you'll need to implement this simple `IMvxTrace` interface - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/Platform/IMvxTrace.cs

With this done... on each platform you should be able to implement a `MySpecialTrace` which implements `IMvxTrace`, and then you should be able to initialise it in Setup using:

```
    protected override void InitializeDebugServices()
    {
         Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTrace>(new MySpecialTrace());
         MvxTrace.Initialize();
    }
```